# Add random text before file name extension

Tags: random, insert, sed, rename

I have this string:

```
2013/07./penguin pingouin pinguino 365.png
```

...that I want to effectively be renamed to

```
2013/07./penguin pingouin pinguino 365${RANDOM}.png
```

I'm thinking that sed might be able to insert random bits 4 spaces inward from the last character in the string. I don't know how to do that (if it's even possible or the best method).

**Background:** This is part of a picture sorting script that I'm trying to incorporate a rename ability when it finds duplicates. The extension is not always `.png`, but it will always be three characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for file in *; do 
  ext="${i##*.}"; 
  mv "$file" "${file%.*}${random}.${ext}"; 
done
```

```
$ random="my random stuff" # 
$ touch "penguin pingouin pinguino 365.png" 
$ ls
penguin pingouin pinguino 365.png
$ for file in *; do 
    ext="${i##*.}"; mv "$file" "${file%.*}${random}.${ext}"; 
  done
$ ls
penguin pingouin pinguino 365my random stuff.png
```

Comment: I came up with the same thing yesterday, actually. I'll give you the answer since I wasn't allowed to answer my own question within eight hours.

Mine was like this:
    EXT=`echo $2 | awk -F. '{print $NF}'`
    ${2%.*}${RANDOM}.${EXT}

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to backup files into a directory:

```
moveto () { 
    file=$1
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then 
        echo "no such file: $file"
        return 1
    fi
    dir=$2;
    if [[ -d "$dir" ]]; then
        echo "no such directory: $dir"
        return 1
    fi
    target="$dir/$(basename "$file")"
    if [[ -f "$target" ]]; then
        base=${target%.???}
        ext=${target##*.}
        prev=("$base"_*)
        for ((i=${#prev[@]}-1; i>=0; i--)); do
            if [[ ${prev[i]} =~ "$base"_0*([0-9]+) ]]; then
                n=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
                mv "${prev[i]}" "$(printf "%s_%03d.%s" "$base" $((n+1)) "$ext")"
            fi
        done
        mv "$target" "$base"_001.$ext
    fi
    mv "$file" "$target"
}
```

The first time you "moveto" a file to a dir (`moveto file.txt backups`), you get "backups/file.txt"
The 2nd time, you'll have "backups/file.txt" and "backups/file_001.txt"
The 3rd time, you'll have "backups/file.txt", "backups/file_001.txt" and  "backups/file_002.txt"
And so on.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should do what you need in sed `sed -r 's/(.[a-zA-Z]+$)/$RANDOM\1'`